# xpath - how to find an embedded li with an input element inside it?

Tags: xpath

Given this HTML:

```
<li class="check_boxes input optional" id="activity_roles_input">
    <fieldset class="choices">
        <legend class="label"><label>Roles</label></legend>
        <input id="activity_roles_none" name="activity[role_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
            <ol class="choices-group">
                <li class="choice">
                    <label for="activity_role_ids_104">
                        <input id="activity_role_ids_104" name="activity[role_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="104" />Language Therapist
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li class="choice">
                    <label for="activity_role_ids_103">
                        <input id="activity_role_ids_103" name="activity[role_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="103" />Speech Therapist
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ol>
    </fieldset>
</li>
```

I am trying to use Selenium and xpath with it.
I am trying to select the first 'checkbox' input element link.
I am having problems selecting the element.
I cannot use the db ID (104) as this is for repeated tests with new ID's each time.  I need to select the 'first' input checkbox, based on it having the text for Language Therapist.

I have tried:

```
xpath=(//li[contains(@id,'activity_roles_input')])//input
```

and

```
xpath=(//li[contains(@id,'activity_roles_input')])//contains('Language Therapist")
```

but it is not finding the element.

When I do:

```
xpath=(//li[contains(@id,'activity_roles_input')])
```

it gets to the input set.  The problem I am having is selecting the first input checkbox control for 'Language Therapist'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, find any `<li>` containing the text and than look for in the descendant of those for the first checkbox.

```
xpath=(//li[contains(., "Language Therapist")]/descendant::input[@type="checkbox"][1])
```

(From Michael)

The above worked for me.  In the end I actually used

```
xpath=(//li[contains(@id,'activity_roles_input')]/descendant::input[@type="checkbox"][1])
```

becuase I liked ID'ing by css ID.

Comment: Works for me (I posted this question).

Answer (score 1):

interesting fact to notice when I try to run this small xsl against your xml.

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="//li[@id ='activity_roles_input']">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:for-each>       
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
    Roles




                    Language Therapist




                    Speech Therapist
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
xpath=(//li[contains(@id,'activity_roles_input')])//input
```

Shouldn't that be

```
xpath=(//li[contains(@id,'activity_roles_input')]//input)
```

or rather

```
xpath=(//li[@id='activity_roles_input']//input)
```

?

Answer (score -1):

```
xpath=(//li[@id='activity_roles_input']//input[1])
```

Comment: Please do not post bare code answers. Include some explanation with your code.